# Simulating homogeneity of variance in linear regression

Tags: r, linear-regression, simulation, sample

I want to visualize some assumptions on regression theory. Starting point is this population and linear regression:

```
set.seed(1234)
runifdisc <- function(n, min = 0, max = 1) sample(min:max, n, replace = T)
x1 <- runifdisc(100000, 1, 10)
e <- runifdisc(100000, 0, 20)
y <- 4 + 2 * x1 + e
dat_pop <- data.frame(x1, e, y)

m_pop <- lm(y ~ x1, data = dat_pop)
```

Since x1 has 10 values, m_pop leads to 10 different predictions for y given x.

```
> table(round(predict(m_pop)))

   16    18    20    22    24    26    28    30    32    34 
10096 10081  9864 10078  9927  9914  9915 10124 10018  9983
```

If I am not mistaken, the predictions of y given x1 should have the same variance for each specific value of x1 in a large number of samples. An assumption that can also be applied to the residuals. However, in my code, the variance varies with the different y values given x1:

```
n <- 1000

vec_y1 <- rep(0, n)
vec_y2 <- rep(0, n)
vec_y3 <- rep(0, n)
vec_y4 <- rep(0, n)
vec_y5 <- rep(0, n)
vec_y6 <- rep(0, n)
vec_y7 <- rep(0, n)
vec_y8 <- rep(0, n)
vec_y9 <- rep(0, n)
vec_y10 <- rep(0, n)

#Draw 1000 samples from dat_pop; in each sample, save the prediction of y given x1
#in vectors vec_y1-vec_y10.
for (i in 1:n){
  s <- dat_pop[sample(nrow(dat_pop), 1000), ]
  m <- lm(y ~ x1, data = s)

  #Prediction for y given x1 == 1
  vec_y1[i] <- m$coefficients[1] +  1 * m$coefficients[2]
  #Prediction for y given x1 == 2
  vec_y2[i] <- m$coefficients[1] +  2 * m$coefficients[2]
  #Prediction for y given x1 == 3
  vec_y3[i] <- m$coefficients[1] +  3 * m$coefficients[2]
  #Prediction for y given x1 == ...
  vec_y4[i] <- m$coefficients[1] +  4 * m$coefficients[2]
  vec_y5[i] <- m$coefficients[1] +  5 * m$coefficients[2]
  vec_y6[i] <- m$coefficients[1] +  6 * m$coefficients[2]
  vec_y7[i] <- m$coefficients[1] +  7 * m$coefficients[2]
  vec_y8[i] <- m$coefficients[1] +  8 * m$coefficients[2]
  vec_y9[i] <- m$coefficients[1] +  9 * m$coefficients[2]
  vec_y10[i] <- m$coefficients[1] +  10 * m$coefficients[2]
}

#Variance of different predictions for y given x1 in the samples above.
#This variance should be equal for all vectors vec_y1-vec_y10.
var(vec_y1)
var(vec_y3)
var(vec_y5)
var(vec_y8)
var(vec_y10)
```

The variance is larger for the lower and upper values of x1.

```
> var(vec_y1)
[1] 0.1234933
> var(vec_y3)
[1] 0.06295427
> var(vec_y5)
[1] 0.03637214
> var(vec_y8)
[1] 0.06016804
> var(vec_y10)
[1] 0.118478
```

My question addresses, on the one hand, my understanding of the assumption from regression theory. Perhaps there is a misunderstanding on my side. On the other hand, the question is about the code that produces the same variance for all y given x1.

Comment: Hi, interesting question... I do not understand the code completely (maybe some comments help). The assumption "Since x1 has 10 values, m_pop leads to 10 different predictions for y given x." is a little confusing. Why does it lead to 10 predictions? and where do you predict something?

Comment: y in dat_pop has 39 values (length(unique(dat_pop$y))). Thats the simulated empirical variable y. However, predicting y in dat_pop using x1 (m_pop <- lm(y ~ x1, data = dat_pop)) leads to 10 different forecasts of y (lets call this predicted variable y_hat). Reason: x1 has 10 values. m_pop predicts one straight line for the relationship between y and x1, that means one value y for one value x1. Differences between those 10 predicted values y_hat and the simulated empirical variable y in dat_pop are residuals. I hope this makes the situation described a little bit more clear.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for clarification. 
Another question : "m$coefficients[1] +  3 * m$coefficients[2]" is what you want to do?
Meaning take the "Intercept plus three times the slope"...

Comment: Yes that is right. "m$coefficients[1] + 3 * m$coefficients[2]" is the prediction of y given x1 == 3. "m$coefficients[1] + 4 * m$coefficients[2]" is the prediction of y given x1 == 4 and so on. The point is: For each prediction of y given x1 (that means 10 predictions), in a large number of samples the variance should be equal.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help to solve it. It took me a while to see it...

The variance is smallest at 5 because it is the mean of your model (x1 values spans from 0 to 10) If you change the model to eg. 1:20, then 10 will have the minimal variance.

You train the model x times in the for loop. every time the predicted slope changes a bit, but most at the ends (1 and 10). And that is the reason behind it. The regression will alway go through the center.

Below are two test samples (two iterations from the loop).

[image]

Comment: That is very helpful. The question is now: Why does the predicted slope changes most at the ends? I mean, it does, as we can see. But going on from regression theory, it should not do that, or am I wrong? That would be against the assumption that the variance for every value y given x should be equal.

Comment: The variance for every value y is equal for one model. But we compare now a set of different models and therefore the variance of y between these models... (In my mind this make sense at the moment, but maybe there is another good explanation)